# getting uv-Coordinates from THREE.js DataTexture

Tags: three.js, textures

I am trying to implement a small Volumerenderer with THREE.js. For that I have a large(at least 65000 elements) array with intensity-values(too large to pass as a uniform array) to the shader where raycasting and all that will happen. I wanted to use THREE.DataTexture for that but I don't seem to have any uv-coordinates in the shader and get the following error:

```
Error: WebGL: vertexAttribPointer: must have valid GL_ARRAY_BUFFER binding 
Error: WebGL: drawArrays: bound vertex attribute buffers do not have sufficient size for given first and count
```

This is my setup:

In the init-function:

```
var data = new Uint8Array(textureArray);
var texture = new THREE.DataTexture(data, 128, 128, THREE.AlphaFormat);
texture.needsUpdate = true;
uniforms = {
texture: {type: "t", value: texture}
}
```

in the vertex-shader:

```
varying vec2 vUv;
void main(){
vUv = uv;
}
```

in the fragment-shader:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
varying vec2 vUv;
```

The shaders are for a THREE.ShaderMaterial on a particleSystem. Everything works fine as long as i don't have the vUv = uv assignment in the the vertex-shader and the Texture works when I put it on a Cube like this:

```
cube = new THREE.CubeGeometry(10,10,10);
material = new THREE.BasicMaterial({map: texture});
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cube, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Has anybody had a similar problem or an idea where my mistake could be?

Comment: were you able to solve this? I'm currently having the same issue

Comment: I got around it but since then I changed a lot in the code so I don't remember what made the difference. I think the problem had to do with uv on the particle system.. Are you using one too? Maybe I can be more helpful if you are more specific about your problem